# Can't launch Spyder on Windows 10

Tags: windows, anaconda, spyder

I've downloaded and installed the latest version of Anaconda but  I can't start the Spyder.I think this starts after installing Tensorflow framework. I'm trying to open Anaconda Navigator but nothing is happening. What can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need of installing tensorflow framework to get spyder worked

After installing the latest version of anaconda. Go to Anaconda prompt, after going to that please type the command:

First make sure spyder get installed by typing

```
>conda list
```

If spyder is there then we can go to the spyder by using

```
>spyder
```

Then spyder will get opened

If not then install spyder by using:

```
>conda install spyder
```